# Is it possible for $x^3-3$ to be a perfect square?

Tags: number-theory

> Is it possible for $x^3-3$ to be a perfect square (or the negative of a perfect square), where $x$ is an integer?

I tried using modular arithmetic to find a contradiction, but couldn't find any. How can we find a contradiction?

Comment: Equivalently, does the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3-3$ have an integral point? This curve is also known as a [Mordell curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordell_curve).

Comment: @lhf Or $-y^2 = x^3-3$.

Comment: $(-1)^3 - 3 = - 2^2$ unless you add further restrictions.

Comment: http://tnt.math.se.tmu.ac.jp/simath/MORDELL/MORDELL- tells us the answer is no.

Comment: @lhf Is there any way to prove it?

Comment: @user19405892 You won't be able to prove it's impossible, unless you change the question. My previous comment gives the explicit example $x=-1,y=2$ with $x^3-3=-y^2$ which satisfies the conditions.

Comment: @dxiv I am asking about proving there are no solutions to the Mordell curve $y^2 = x^3-3$.

Comment: @user19405892: since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ has class number one a promising approach is to factor both $y^2+3$ and $x^3$ over the ring of Eisenstein integers and derive a contradiction from $y^2+3 = x^3$.

Answer (score 3):

The ring of [Eisenstein integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer) is a Euclidean domain, hence a UFD. It follows that, in order to find the integer solutions of $(y+\sqrt{-3})(y-\sqrt{-3})=x^3$, it is enough to study the structure of cubes in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ where $\omega=\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$. Since

$$\begin{eqnarray*} (a+b\omega)^3 &=& (a^3-b^3-3ab^2)+3ab(a+b)\omega\\
&=&(a^3-b^3-3ab^2)+3ab(a+b)\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2} \end{eqnarray*}$$
and $3ab(a+b)=\pm 2$ has no integer solutions, the Mordell equation
$$ y^2+3 = x^3$$
has no integer solutions, too.

Comment: Number theory is not my field at all, so I am probably missing something simple, but would you mind explaining how the fact that $3ab(a+b) = \pm 2$ has no integer solutions allows you to conclude anything about the Mordell  equation?

Comment: @JasonDeVito: the Mordell equation has an integer solution **iff** there is some cube in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ whose imaginary part is $\pm\sqrt{3}$. But a cube in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ cannot have imaginary part $\pm\sqrt{3}$, so we are doomed.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still a bit hazy.  Specifically, after scanning this :  http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf, (bottom of 5th page) - it seems as if we need to know that $y + \sqrt{-3}$ and $y-\sqrt{-3}$ are relatively prime in the Eisenstein integers.    Is this easy to see?  (After we establish this, I think I follow the rest of the argument.)

Comment: @JasonDeVito: the Euclidean algorithm works in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ as well as in $\mathbb{Z}$. If $y+\sqrt{-3}$ and its conjugate have a non-trivial common divisor, it has to be a divisor of $2\sqrt{-3}$, too.

Comment: Thanks again.  I was able to push your suggestion into a proof, but it's probably not what you had in mind.  In short, I showed a) $2\cdot \sqrt{-3} = 2(1+2\omega)$ is the prime factorization of $2\sqrt{-3}$, b)  y must be even (reduce Mordell mod 8), so if $2$ divides $y\pm \sqrt{-3}$, then it divides $\sqrt{-3}$ (contradicting primeness of $\sqrt{-3}$).    Thus, only possible nontrivial gcd is $\sqrt{-3}$.  c)  If the gcd is $\sqrt{-3}$, this implies $y$ is $0$ mod $3$, which, via Mordell, implies $x$ is.  If $y = 3a$, $x = 3b$, the Mordell equation turns into $3a^2 + 1 = 9b^3$...

Comment: ...which has no solutions mod $3$.  Thanks again for your patience!

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio : I am worried that your argument makes no use of the LHS of the Mordell equation, except the fact that it belongs to Z. Actually you compute (a+b.omega)^3 to get 3ab(a+b) = + or -2, but this makes sense only if ab is not 0. In particular, if b = 0, the calculations in the Eisenstein ring give nothing more than the original Mordell equation.

Comment: @nguyenquangdo: that does not make sense, $y^2+3$ always splits over $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$. My argument above is just a minor variation on the propositions of Conrad here: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf

Comment: Ah, I see now. You use the UFD property to deduce that any factor on the LHS must be a cube in the Eisenstein ring. My apologies if I skipped that starting point.

Comment: @nguyenquangdo: exactly, but no apology was needed :)